# How does Java distinguish between libraries and applications?

Tags: java, shared-libraries

Windows applications make a distinction between libraries (DLLs) and applications (EXEs). Does Java make an equivalent distinction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kind of.

Most Java programs are stored in a .jar file.

If the .jar has a `main` method specified, it can be called similarly to a .exe where it starts the program execution.  You can do this with `java -jar program.jar`.

But any .jar file can be loaded from another one and the code within it loaded, similarly to a .dll.  This can be done even if the 'library' jar has a `main` method, it just won't be called automatically.

Comment: Nice answer.  One nitpick is that jar files specify a main *class* not a main *method*.

Comment: In addition, jar files can *contain* more than one main method.

Comment: Actually it is a method.  The class name can be anything, but the method must be called `main` for the JVM to recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

The question is nonsensical.  Java compiles into bytecode class files which are interpreted by a virtual machine.

You can throw a bunch of class files inside a zip file and call it a jar, but Java has no analogue of an exe or dll.

Comment: Actually, it does. Everything with `public static void main(String[])` is analogous to an exe, and everything with a class file is analogous to a dll.

Comment: It's not quite analogous to an exe. The OS doesn't know how to execute the file/binary on it's own, it's only that the JVM knows how to load the JAR and process the main() method.

Comment: @glowcoder I can see what you're saying -- I guess it's how far you want to step back and abstract things.  Java has no files that behave or are used like dlls or executables.  Every Java class file is equal in the eyes of the JVM.

Comment: @matt That's why it's analogous, but not equivilant. Exes have to have a point of entry too :) @Jonathon you're right that it's a matter of how far you want to step back. Every analogy has points at which it breaks down.

Comment: Java doesn't have EXEs and DLLs, but it could be said to have things "analagous" to EXEs and DLLs, as others have described. Actually I've seen products advertised that will compile a Java program to an EXE, though I've never used one.

Answer (score 0):

Java has jar files (Java ARchive).  This can run as the main program or as additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that an "executable JAR" (which has a main class declared in its manifest) is the Java equivalent of an EXE, while other JARs are more like DLLs.

The similarity is probably closer than you realize since AFAIK, in Windows the difference is rather small as well, the file formats largely the same and you can execute code from a DLL via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Java's equivalent of a library is a jar file where you can package code together.

In addition you can package a manifest file into the jar called META-INF/manifest.mf with a directive that says run this class when the jar is invoked by the java runtime in the following way:
java -jar MyApp.jar

This gets you the equivalent of libraries and executables.